# Rails: putting customized gems on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I'm using the [jquery file upload gem](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) and it has a 'auto-upload' variable I just want to set it to true and get it to work on heroku. How could I change the gem and save it inside my app?

Should I just download it off github and drop it in `'vendor/gems/jquery_file_upload'` ?

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Comment: could you specify link to that file where you want to change?

Comment: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js @SachinSingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done with other gems that I use on Heroku that need to be changed is the following:

1. Fork the gem in your own github repo.
2. Make the change you need in your fork.
3. Update your `Gemfile` to point to your fork of the gem.

This will make bundler pull your fork of the gem (with your change) and load that in your app.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

you can also override the options values like this

```
$(#your_form_id).fileupload(
   'options', {
        autoUpload: true
   }
)
```